# How to expose .net object to remote c++ client

Tags: .net, c++, client

We have a .net library developed in C#.
It needs to be exposed to a unmanaged C++ client thats available in a remote machine.
By what means could we resolve this?

Comment: Unmanaged code accesses .NET functionality via COM. You can do that client side and use unmanaged remoting (e.g. DCOM, basic RPC or even Corba). Or you can do that on the remote machine and use .NET remoting. I have no experience with the latter. In early days it was based on SOAP, probably it's been elaborated on and called something more fancy now. But that's the big picture. Check docs for details (or, as we used to say in the old days, RTFM, like MIT still has RTFM web site, but politically incorrect now...). Cheers,

Comment: Or, what exactly do you mean by "exposed"?

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I'd like to add more clarity on the problem:

1. In the server side, We have a windows service used for hosting the .net remoting object.
2. A C# wrapper library is used to access this remoting object.
3. I need to expose this wrapper library to a remote machine were we do not have .net framework installed.  Its a windows xp machine.
4. The remote machine has a win32/ATL/MFC c++ client that needs to make calls to this wrapper library which does not reside locally.

Could you get it?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what OS you are working on.  If it is Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 (or later, for future correctness) you should research WWSAPI as that is Microsoft's native code implementation of WCF.  Earlier Windows OSes may require use of third party SOAP libraries designed for interop with WCF.  I'm not sure of the status of these these days.

Another option, assuming the above isn't viable, would be to write a C# or C++/CLI proxy on the remote machine that the unmanaged client can talk to using standard inter-process communications like RPC, shared memory, COM or other technologies.  The proxy then handles the WCF calls to the C# server.  This should be workable in most scenarios.

Edit: I'm assuming use of WCF for remote communications using .Net code.  For answers regarding other potential items, someone else will have to answer because my knowledge in those areas are a lot more sketchy.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I'd like to add more clarity on the problem:

1. In the server side, We have a windows service used for hosting the .net remoting object.
2. A C# wrapper library is used to access this remoting object.
3. I need to expose this wrapper library to a remote machine were we do not have .net framework installed.  Its a windows xp machine.
4. The remote machine has a win32/ATL/MFC c++ client that needs to make calls to this wrapper library which does not reside locally.

Could you get it?

Comment: If the remote machine doesn't have the .Net framework you will either have to look into third-party libraries that can interop with WCF or use some other inter-machine communication technology.